# SQL selecting DISTINCT values across 2 columns regardless of their order?

Tags: mysql

This seems like it should be such a simple one, but for the life of me I can't find the answer anywhere. Let's say I have the following data :

```
messageID  senderID recipientID 
        2       999           6
        4        23         999
        5        15         999 
        6       999          15
        7        15         999
```

I want to only select unique conversations. So to me, message 5 (15, 999), 6 (999,15) and 7 (15,999) are from the same conversation and need to be shown only once not 3 times. If I use the SQL statement :

```
SELECT DISTINCT senderID, recipientID FROM messages
```

it of course treats message 5, 6 and 7 as each being distinct. How can I get it to recognize that if the sender and recipient are she same REGARDLESS of the order, it's to be counted as only one?

**** UPDATE ****

something I didn't realize would be an issue... let's say in the table above, I also have a column called "notes" but I DON'T want it to be analyzed for "distinctness". I just want it included in the final query results.  How can I include the notes column (or any other column) while requiring only senderID and recipientID to be distinct??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    case when senderID > recipientID then recipientID else senderID end lowerID,
    case when senderID < recipientID then recipientID else senderID end higherID
FROM messages
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, this solves the original problem but one thing : there are other fields in the messages table that I omitted for clarity. How can i include them in your query without it also looking for distinct values on them as well?

Comment: @Rocks: Which of those values would you want to see? If you update the question to include those values and your desired output, it should be possible to answer the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You can se `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select distinct least(senderID, recipientID) as id1, greatest(senderID, recipientID) as id2
from messages m;
```

If you want to ensure that the resulting rows are actually in the original table:

```
select distinct senderId, recipientId 
from messages m
where senderId <= recipientId
union all
select distinct senderId, recipientId  
from messages m
where senderId > recipientId and
      not exists (select 1 from messages m2
                  where m2.senderId = m.recipientId and
                        m2.recipientId = m.senderId
                 );
```